# Prolog: lexicographic comparison and split a list

Tags: prolog

Given atom x, I am trying to split a list into one with atoms smaller than x and one with atoms equal to or greater than x.

For example)

```
%% split(d,[a,b,c,d,e,f],AtomSmall, AtomBig) should give me
%% AtomSmall = [a,b,c], AtomBig = [d,e,f]
```

Below is what I've tried so far. I get the concept.However my code includes the atom that is equivalent to x in `AtomSmall` list, not `AtomBig`, although I check the case with before predicate.
For example)

```
%% split(d,[a,b,c,d,e,f],AtomSmall, AtomBig) gives me
%% AtomSmall = [a,b,c,d], AtomBig = [e,f]


before(X,Y):-atom_codes(X,A),atom_codes(Y,B),small(A,B).
small([],[]).
small([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):-H1<H2.
small([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):-H1=:=H2,small(T1,T2).

split(X,[],[],[]).
split(X,[H1|T1],[H1|Small],Big):-before(H1,X),split(X,T1,Small,Big).
split(X,[H1|T1],Small,[H1|Big]):-not(before(H1,X)),split(X,T1,Small,Big).
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

In SWI-Prolog, you can use [partition](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=partition/4)/4 from library(lists) and the standard order comparison (@>)/2:

```
?- lists:partition(@>(d),[a,b,c,d,e,f],L,R).
L = [a, b, c],
R = [d, e, f].
```

Since the order of arguments in comparison is fixed passing the pivot in as first argument, a lambda expression (using library([yall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)), needs a recent version) can help to give a more intuitive reading:

```
?- partition([E]>>(E@<d),[a,b,c,d,e,f],L,R).
L = [a, b, c],
R = [d, e, f].
```

Anyway, your code could be patched like this:

```
split(_,[],[],[]).
split(X,[H1|T1],[H1|Small],Big):-H1@<X,split(X,T1,Small,Big).
split(X,[H1|T1],Small,[H1|Big]):- \+ H1@<X,split(X,T1,Small,Big).

?- split(d,[a,b,c,d,e,f],L,R).
L = [a, b, c],
R = [d, e, f] ;
false.
```

Comment: If I were to do it the way I did it, why is my code not working correctly as I intended?

Answer (score 0):

Your `before/2` predicate succeeds if the arguments are lexicographically equivalent. For example, `before(a, a)` is true. That's because your 3rd clause allows equal values throughout the list until the base case finally succeeds with two empty lists.

In addition, something you haven't encountered yet evidently, is that `before(X, Y)` will fail if `X` and `Y` are different length atoms. For example, `before(ab, abc)` will fail. So your `small/2` needs to take care of that case as well.

A refactoring of `small/2` will fix that:

```
% 1st clause is fixed so unequal length atoms are handled properly
small([], _).
small([H1|_], [H2|_]) :- H1 < H2.
% 3rd clause is fixed so that equal atoms won't succeed here
small([H,H1|T1], [H,H2|T2]) :- small([H1|T1], [H2|T2]).
```

But... you don't need to go through all that with `before/2`. Prolog knows how to compare, in a sensible way, atoms (and general Prolog terms) using the `@<` and `@>` operators, as @CapelliC indicated in his answer. So your `before/2` just becomes:

```
before(X, Y) :- X @< Y.
```

And you don't need `small/2` at all. That's basically the second solution that @CapelliC showed in his answer.